# HTML form page redirect not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have an online form on my business' internal site.  When the form is submitted, the form goes through an error check scripted in Javascript.  If everything checks out, then it gets sent to an email for evaluation and the page is supposed to redirect to a confirmation page.  However, when I click on Send, the email gets sent but the page does not change.  Here is the code I am having issues with:

```
emailForm(myForm, myForm.emailTo.value, myForm.emailSubject.value, myForm.emailLevel.value, 'server'),
location.href = formsubmitted.html;
```

If I remove the emailForm function, it will redirect the page.  This same code works on other forms I have so I'm not sure why it's stopping me.  I've used up all of my resources and am unsure how to fix this.  Please help.  Thanks

Comment: It sounds like location.href is never reached (or maybe formsubmitted.html was invalid url?).
Try putting a ```console.log()``` to see what's going on there.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the comma instead of a semicolon at the end of the `emailForm` call?